# How to disable combination of keys using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to disable view source shortcut key for IE using JavaScript.
To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I am using the following function:

```
function disableCopy() {
     // current pressed key
     var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
     if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c")) {
         // disable key press porcessing
         event.returnValue = false;
     }
}
```

Can any one suggest how to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> combination?

Comment: You realise this will not ultimately prevent people from viewing the source if they're determined, right?

Comment: You want to disable viewing HTML source code?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The question may be flawed in concept, but for what it is, it's asked well enough and the OP shows a code attempt. +1.

Comment: The web is open. If your page is good and people want to view your code then you should feel proud of yourself. If you're going to waste your energy preventing people from doing so then no one will bother reading through your code. It's not worth the hassle.

Comment: Disabling Ctrl+C is one step away from breaking the back button. I really hope you've got an exceptional reason for this major annoyance.

Comment: This is an excellent way to make no one ever want to visit your webpage again.

Comment: People tried to stop you copying text or images from pages by disabling right click. Brilliant - guess I'll have to try one of the other 3 or 4 ways of copying what I want. The bottom line is: if it ends up in someone's browser, don't think you can stop them using it. That's the client-side trade-off.

Comment: I know i cannot restrict the end user to view source. I just wanted to ensure that the user takes few more steps to view my source not for all but for some of my pages.
Hope you understand my intension/requirement.

Comment: Everyone assumes this question is being asked only as a way to try to protect content. Even if it is, techniques to fulfill his request would also be useful for JavaScript apps that want to rebind those shortcuts. Why not just answer instead of ridiculing the OP?

Answer (score 2):

Every browser has its built-in functionality to view the source code or the webpage. We can do one thing. That is disabling right click in your page.

For disable right click use the following code:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function disableselect(e){
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
//if IE4+
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
//if NS6
if (window.sidebar){
document.onmousedown=disableselect
document.onclick=reEnable
}
</SCRIPT>
```

**Remember one thing. We can view this source using firebug or some other third party tools. So we cant do this 100%.**

Comment: I think the comments below the question render it unworthy of answer. Not in a harsh way - just that, as has been pointed out, preventing access to the source code is a none-starter.

Comment: @Utkanos +1. That and the fact the code is *grossly* out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You should not really prevent viewing code. Why?

Reasons

1. Eventually after all your efforts, if someone is determined he can still see your code.
2. You will defame your website by doing this.
3. You will kind-of behave like a "noob", as normally fellow developers see codes and they will break through your security measure by just disabling javascript.
4. There is no sensitive information in your code(I suppose) which can be used to pose a threat. But, if you have some code which can be used against the website you should really look into removing that code and making the website secure.

Disable combinations

```
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.altKey && (e.keyCode === 67||e.keyCode === 86)) {//Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
            alert('not allowed');
        }
        return false;
};​
```

Any ways, because I know how to do it, I will show you.

Here to disable right-click:

```
function clickIE() {if (document.all) {return false;}} 
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {return false;}}} 
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;} 
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;} 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
```

Comment: The variable *message* in the bottom code is utterly useless, it'll never get output.

Comment: "e.keyCode === 67&& e.keyCode === 86" I don't see when this becomes true..

also, it should be alt key not the ctrl key

Comment: @0xc0de Thanks, for it, I removed the block.

Answer (score 0):

alt + V + C is a very odd combination to have. Although following code will work, it's sort of hackish.

```
if (event.altKey) {
    if (event.keyCode == 67 && window.prevKey == 86)
        event.preventDefault();
    else if (event.keyCode == 86 && window.prevKey == 67)
        event.preventDefault();
    window.prevKey = event.keyCode
}
```